# How do I show that a stationary point of $\nabla f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is hyperbolic if and only if $D^2f(p)$ is nondegenerate?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function, and let $F = \nabla f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be the corresponding gradient field.

A point $p \in U$ is a stationary point of $F$ if and only if $Df(p) = 0$.

Now I want to show that the eigenvalues of $DF(p)$ are all real and that the stationary point $p$ is hyperbolic if and only if the bilinear form $D^2f(p)$ is nondegenerate.

I know that $p$ is a hyperbolic stationary point of $F$ if all the eigenvalues of $DF(p)$ have nonzero real parts.

I am stuck and don't know where to start. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As a $d\times d$ matrix, $DF$ is the Hessian of $f$, so is real and symmetric, hence by the spectral theorem can be (pointwise) orthogonally diagonalized (in particular has real eigenvalues).

Next, prove the linear algebra fact that for a bilinear functional on $\Bbb{R}^d$, being non-degenerate is equivalent to some (equivalently, every) matrix representation being invertible, which is equivalent to having non-zero determinant. In the case of a diagonalizable matrix, it’s equivalent to having non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. I am somewhat confused about the difference between $D^2f(p)$ and $DF(p)$. To me, they both seem to be the Hessian of f, but the exercise uses both notations as if they were different. Is there a difference?

Comment: @Kajice because you defined $F$ to be the gradient vector field, it by definition means $F(p)\in\Bbb{R}^d$ is the vector such that $\langle F(p),\cdot\rangle= Df_p(\cdot)$ (i.e $Df$ takes values by definition in the dual space $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^d,\Bbb{R})=(\Bbb{R}^d)^*$, and we have to use an inner product to recover the unnaturally familiar gradient vector).  So, $DF_p\in\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^d,\Bbb{R}^d)$ is related to the bilinear form $D^2f_p\in\text{Hom}^2(\Bbb{R}^d;\Bbb{R})$ as follows: for all $v,w\in\Bbb{R}^d$, $\langle DF_p(v),w\rangle=D^2f_p[v,w]$.

Comment: If you try to extract matrix representations, say with respect to the usual basis of $\Bbb{R}^d$, you’ll get exactly the Hessian matrix of $f$ at $p$, namely the matrix with entries $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}(p)$. In $\Bbb{R}^d$ it may seem like I’m just being pedantic and unnecessarily complicating this, but be sure you understand things. The point is one should maintain respect for the distinction between a vector space and its dual (or just avoid introducing $F$ all together).